# How to see the bones through the mesh?

Tags: rigging

Bones are on layer 9:

[image]

I already turn X-Ray on "Bones", but bones didn't appear...

[image]

How can I make the bones and mesh become together likes this:
 [image]

This came from [this](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/26225) site.

[If you want to download the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uAccgqYL1qkdfoBdVfvEMJM0JEOwKVvf). (You have to create an account to the site in order to download it, so I upload it on Google Drive if you want to download it. The size is 2 MB.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the bones and mesh become together?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110166/how-can-i-make-the-bones-and-mesh-become-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clicking layer 9 and then shift clicking the layer where your mesh is?

If so, go over to the panel where the camera is. Find the armature selection and click on it, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go between tabs and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Your bones should appear. Remember that both the mesh layer and the armature layer have to be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 12):

In 2.8, it is now called **In Front**. It can be found at `Properties > Object Data tab > Viewport Display section > In Front`.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is for **For Blender 2.91**, I just wish the developers would stop messing with the workflow and renaming stuff

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Object Properties under display enable x-ray [image]

Answer (score 1):

Every object seems to have its own xray setting. Try switching xray off in body and on in armature. Something I worked out earlier

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 4.0, the feature is in the Object Data Properties tab.

[image: Blender Armature "In Front" Feature]